# Is "that which" grammatical in the sentence "I have that which I should have told you summers ago", and if so, how?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, relative-pronouns, demonstratives, which-what

This is my first question although I have been reading you for a long time. My question is: can *that which* be used with the meaning of *something*?

For me, *that* is a demonstrative pronoun, so you can say *I have **that which** you seek* (meaning that thing you’re seeking), but not this:

> “I am so delighted to have you back, it never occurred to me that you should have attained your full height by now, boy,” the elder Giant admitted with a slight heightening of his color. “I have **that which** I should have told you summers ago. Forgive me. I see by not telling you my secret, I have caused you needless anxiety. Just how tall are you?”

Is that grammatical? If so, how does it work syntactically? What kind of a clause is this really?

If this is not grammatical, what norm of English usage or syntax is it violating?

Comment: Yes, it sounds odd there. On the other hand, having ***something** to say* sounds ok.

Comment: Thank you @Lawrence and thank you tchrist for editing my post.

Comment: If you switch it to an object it sounds less awkward: “I have that which I should have given you summers ago" to see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions here: whether the sentence is unusual or ungrammatical on the one hand, and what sort of a clause it is. Here’s the sentence of your concern as found in your citation:

1. I have **that which** I should have told you summers ago.

The reason is sounds a bit funny is because things you tell someone are normally abstractions like opinions or situations, positions or tales, secrets or truths. Therefore they are not in the same category as tangible objects that you can keep in your possession, to “have and to hold” as the saying goes.

If this were a tangible item, adding an *about* would help a little:

2. I have **that which** I should have told **about** you summers ago.

The text following that sentence suggests that what he’s talking about here is a secret. That’s what’s unusual here. A more expected formulation might be:

3. **There is** something (that) I should have told you (about) summers ago.

or perhaps:

4. I**’ve got** something (that) I should have told you about summers ago.

Intangibles like truths and tales are more often known than possessed. For example

5. I **know** that which I should have told you summers ago.

In any case, the clause beginning with *that which* serves as the direct object of the main verb. Under most modern analysis, we would not call this instance of *that* a relative pronoun, let alone a demonstrative one.  Demonstratives are words like *this, these, that, those*. They can be used in front of a noun as a demonstrative determiner taking the place of the definite article’s slot in the noun phrase, or they can be used by themselves substantively as standalone demonstrative pronouns.

Perhaps there’s an argument to be made that is a pronominal *that* standing in for *the thing*. That argument would be strengthen by showing that a different demonstrative pronoun could have been used here, like *those* standing in for a plural *the things* or *the people*.

6. I know (of) **those things which** I should have told (about) you summers ago.
7. I know **those which/who(m)** you’re talking about.

But another way to look at *that which* is for *that* to be a complementizer like *whether* and *if* can be. It alternates with *the thing (that/which)* if definite, and *a thing* or *something (that/which)* if indefinite. More commonly the heavier formulation *the thing that/which* gets replaced by a simple *what* to create an embedded *wh‑* clause:

8. I know **that which** you need.
9. I know **the thing that** (*or* **which**) you need.
10. I know **what** you need.

When it’s not *things that* but rather *people that/who(m)*, we can use *who(m)* instead of *what*:

11. I know **those which** you need.
12. I know **those whom** you need.
13. I know **the people that** (*or* **who[m]**) you need.
14. I know **someone (who[m], that, which)** you need.
15. I know **who(m)** you need.

Embedded *wh‑* clauses like these are considered embedded interrogative clauses under a small set of possible predicates including *know*, but are held to be fused relatives in most other cases. If it’s a fused relative, you can add *‑ever* to *what* to say *whatever* for things:

16. I can recommend **that which** you need.
17. I can recommend **the thing that** you need.
18. I can recommend **what** you need.
19. I can recommend **whatever** you need.

Or for people when using *who(m)*, add *‑ever* to *who(m)* to make it *who*(m)ever*:

20. I can recommend **the people that/who(m)** you need.
21. I can recommend **who(m)ever** you need.

When there are several possible equivalent ways of saying the very same thing as we have here, longer versions often feel heavier and more cumbersome than shorter versions. They’re probably less common and so may sound more formal. This makes the choice of *something (that)* or *that which* sound less casual and more unusual, especially *that which*.

This may nonetheless have been a deliberate choice by the author, who may have had reasons for placing a heavier or less usual expression in the mouth of this character in particular. That’s something we can’t really address without getting into literary analysis, which would not only require knowing much more about the piece that your citation comes from, it would also be off-topic for our site.

Comment: Bizarre that someone downvoted this comprehensive answer. I wonder what tiny detail peeved them? Anyway, +1 from me.